# Can I “reuse” Google search results in my application?

Tags: google-search-api

I would like to understand if and how it is possible to achieve the following:

- Create an app that sends search requests to Google (search requests
  inputted by a user!)
- Fetch the search results present in a different
  format/graphics/layout the search results to the user.
- Is that possible or Google would prevent me from doing such a thing? (via a
  CAPTCHA for example)

If it is possible **what kind of instrument would I need to use to capture (parse?) the search results???**

My application would be developed for Android.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Screen-scraping the search results from the Google search site is a violation of [their terms of service](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/zf3S2Y--X9I).  I don't think they would use CAPTCHA to prevent you from doing so, but you might get a letter from their lawyers.

However, you could use the [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview) which allows you to search Google and customize layout of the results.  However, you need to acquire a developer key and also follow [their terms of service](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/terms).

Also, Android has a search component built into it that you can probably use.  See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html.

Comment: Actually, they do use CAPTCHA if they detect a bursty IP.